# Prevent installed application from launching during silent installation

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I have a setup file called `sample.exe` that is not built by me.
When it is launched, at the final step of installation wizard, it has a checkbox asking user if they would like to launch the program after installation is done, and by default that checkbox is ticked.

Now, I would like to execute `sample.exe` silently using `/VERYSILENT`.
It was able to silently install that program. But the problem is, after silent installation, the installed program is launched, which is not what I want.

My question is, how do I make it so that program is not launched by default when performing silent installation?

Answer (score 2):

If you can re-build the installer, use the `skipifsilent` flag.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent
```

See [[Run] & [UninstallRun] sections](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) in Inno Setup documentation.

---

If you cannot rebuild it, there's no way. You cannot control running the application at the end of the installation using command-line, nor installation settings file (`/loadinf=`) .

Answer (score -1):

This [link](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection)  provides information about the auto launch of apps after installation. Inorder to remove the auto launch feature in your setup, you got to remove [RUN] section ( [RUN] section is optional ] and rebuild the setup

Comment: Well, you've copied the `postinstall` flag description from help, emphasizing two words as bold. So, now what ?

Comment: If he read that section, he will understand. He got to remove the [Run] section (The [Run] section is optional, and specifies any number of programs to execute after the program has been successfully installed, but before the Setup program displays the final dialog. )

Comment: I don't get that. Maybe OP will.